# Send data from edittext to listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have created two `Activities` (`MainActivity`, `ListActivity`) and in `MainActivity`, I have an `EditText` and a save-button.

In `ListActivity`, I have a `ListView`.

I want to save the value/data/string text that is written in `EditText` and send it to the other `Activity` in the `ListView`.

This is how it looks now, but I think I know what I'm missing but don't know how to do it.

MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", et.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the ListActivity.

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    }
}
```

Now the text is saved in data-string, but how paste it in `ListView`?

Comment: Why are you using listview for single string why not textview?

Comment: Everytime I write something in EditText, I want it to be saved in the ListView. If I use TextView, then the old text that was saved will be replaced with the new one. Thats not what I want to do.

Comment: Can you can use a static ArrayList in second activity and update it instead of sending message. Hope you'll get my lead.

Comment: @DMT82 did u get the Answer ? if yes can u SHare pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63547010/android-how-to-pass-the-previous-activity-intent-into-a-listview/63547174#63547174

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create `ArrayAdapter<String>` object and set it to your `ListView`:

```
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
listItems.add(data);
String[] items = {};
items = listItems.toArray(new String[listItems.size()]);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to create a List Container, most used is the ArrayList, then you will have to create a ListAdapater which will inflate your data list to your ListView you can find a good article explaining it here : http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to add things in a ListView :

```
listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

while (...) {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(stuff);
    listItem.add(map);
}

s = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.list,
                       new String[] {"title", "desc"}, new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.desc});
listV.setAdapter(s);
```

Comment: i misunderstood the question the first time so here is the new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `String` from the `TextView` and then add that to an `ArrayAdapter<String>` and then set that as the `Adapter` for the `ListView`

Pseudo code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) getViewById(...);
String s = textView.getText();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(...);
adapter.add(s);
ListView lv = (ListView) getViewById(...)
lv.setAdapter(adapter)
```

And if I understand your question correctly you want to first populate the `ListView` and then send that to another activity. If this is the case, don't try to do that, just create an `ArrayList` of the String(s) and pass that and then create the `ListView` in the activity that needs it.

EDIT:

To solve your problem you can use a `Bundle` to send an `ArrayList<String>` to your other activity then just build an `ArrayAdapter` similar to my above code to populate the `ListView` Something like:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("ArrayListOfStrings", yourArrayList);
```

Then in your other Activity (YourActivity) you can do:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 ArrayList<String> myList = extras.getStringArrayList("ArrayListOfStrings");
```

Comment: No, you did understand it wrong. I have two different Activities. One of them have a button and an edittext, the other activity have the ListView.
When you write something in the EditText and save it, it will send the text/data to the other Activity there the ListView are.