# Edit Text as Parent and its Text View as Child to Expandable listView

Tags: android, android-studio, treeview, expandablelistview

I am trying to send the Edit text into expandable list view. First Edit Text.Sorry i could not post my screen shot due to reputation purpose should be a parent and second should be stored as its child in expandable list view after clicking the save Button.

This is my Main.Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Heading for your Field"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textin"
        android:layout_width="237dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your Options"/>

 </LinearLayout>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Save"
    android:onClick="save_button"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

By clicking on Add button i can add the text from the EditTex of id textin *dynamically*. These this easily happens. This is my main Activity

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText textIn,txtHeading;
Button buttonAdd,btnsave;
TextView textViewOut;
LinearLayout container;

ExpandableDataPump expandableDataPump;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewOut = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textout);
    textIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    txtHeading = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heading);
    buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);


    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);

            TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);

            textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());


            Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                }});

            container.addView(addView);
        }});

    btnsave =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                expandableDataPump.getData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You have an   
  ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                }



        }
    });

}
public  class ExpandableDataPump {
    public  HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


        List<String> childs = new ArrayList<String>();
        childs.add(textIn.getText().toString());
        expandableListDetail.put(txtHeading.getText().toString(), childs);

        return expandableListDetail;
    }
}
}
```

This is my Expandable list class that contains Expandable list view in it's XML:

```
public class ExpandableList extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;
MainActivity.ExpandableDataPump expandableDataPump;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list);


    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

    expandableListDetail = expandableDataPump.getData();
    expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
    expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                            + " -> "
                            + expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
 }}
```

And this is my Adapter Class:

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends 
BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitile;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> expandableListDetail;


 public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context,List<String>  
 expandableLIstTitle,
                               HashMap<String,List<String>>    
expandableListDetail){
this.context = context;
this.expandableListTitile = expandableLIstTitle;
this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return 
  this.expandableListDetail.
  get(this.expandableListTitile.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int 
 expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, 
 ViewGroup parent) {
    final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition,   
  expandedListPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,   
  null);
    }
    TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
    expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {        return 
 this.expandableListDetail.
  get(this.expandableListTitile.get(listPosition))
            .size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitile.get(listPosition);
 }

 @Override
 public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitile.size();
 }

 @Override
 public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
 }

 @Override
 public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,   
 null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int    
expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

I am trying to send the edit text values to expandable list view. am i going right?Please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Code according to this. I have done this for you.

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private String expandableListTitile;
private ArrayList<String> expandableListDetail;


public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, String expandableLIstTitle,
                                   ArrayList<String> expandableListDetail){
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitile = expandableLIstTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitile;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText textIn, txtHeading;
Button buttonAdd, btnsave;
TextView textViewOut;
LinearLayout container;
protected static final String Shared = null;
ExpandableDataPump expandableDataPump;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    expandableDataPump = new ExpandableDataPump();


    textViewOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textout);
    textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textin);
    txtHeading = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heading);
    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);


    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);

            TextView textOut = (TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);

            textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());


            Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                }
            });

            container.addView(addView);
        }
    });

    btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExpandableList.class);
                String Heading = txtHeading.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("Heading", Heading);

                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Options", (ArrayList<String>) expandableDataPump.getData());
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have an ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });

}

public class ExpandableDataPump {
    public List<String> getData() {
        List<String> childs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 2; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (container.getChildAt(i) instanceof RelativeLayout) {
                childs.add(((TextView) container.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textout)).getText().toString());

            }
        }
        return childs;

    }
}
}
```

This is your ExpandableListActivity

```
public class ExpandableList extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String Shared = null;

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
String expandableListTitle;
ArrayList<String> expandableListDetail;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list);


    expandableListDetail = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Options");

    expandableListTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("Heading");


    expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);


    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle + " List Expanded.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle + " List Collapsed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle
                            + " -> "
                            + expandableListDetail/*.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition)*/, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}}
```

If this doesn't help feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I did some quick googleling and this post is I think somewhat familiar to yours, From what it looks like you are going in the right direction:

[Send data from edittext to listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081383/send-data-from-edittext-to-listview)

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not about List view. I wanted this to be sent into ExpandableList View. :)